# Gradlew can't reserve 3G heap memory. Properties are set to 1G

Tags: gradle, heap-memory, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I have a new Gradle problem. I managed to setup the eclipse workspace for forge 1.7.10. But I can't do it for forge 1.10.2, 1.11.2 or 1.12.2
My gradle.properties are setting -Xmx to 1G. When I try to decompile MC, the Error "Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap" occures, but the heap space is set to 1G, not 3G. The Error code isn't helpful too:

```
13:46:04.822 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe''

13:46:04.906 [QUIET] [system.out] Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap

13:46:04.913 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED

13:46:04.914 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)

13:46:04.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':decompileMc'

13:46:04.918 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :decompileMc FAILED

13:46:04.918 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :decompileMc (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.871 secs.
13:46:04.919 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 12.474 secs, idle: 0.011 secs

13:46:04.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

13:46:04.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

13:46:04.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

13:46:04.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:

13:46:04.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':decompileMc'.

13:46:04.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

13:46:04.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

13:46:04.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:

13:46:04.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

13:46:04.931 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]

13:46:04.932 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED

13:46:04.932 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]

13:46:04.932 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 28.788 secs
```

Can anyone help me so my gradle problems are finally out of this world?

Answer (score 0):

## 1 GB is not enough to store 3 GB worth of needed data.

The JVM wants 3 GB of space and you told it that its maximum of 1 GB. You didn't give it enough and it needs more than what you gave it.

Raise the -Xmx to 3GB.

Comment: I got the solution, somewhere a 32 bit java was hiding that I didn't see. I removed it and it worked

Comment: Those pesky alternate installs